# Is it possible to say if the intersection of perpendicular bisectors of sides of a triangle is outside it,it has an angle more than $90$?

Tags: geometry

Is it possible to say if the intersection of perpendicular bisectors of sides of a triangle is outside it,it has an angle more than $90$?

I have saw the lemma that is reverse of it But I can't find a proof for that too.This is a lemma that if it is true my question will solved using this if you want I can put the whole question.

Comment: What is the statement of "the reverse of it"?  It's probably easy to prove if the angles of a triangle are all at most 90, then the intersect of perpendicular bisects are interior and perimeter to the triangle.  So if the intersection is outside, then an angle must be more than 90.

Comment: @fleablood by "reverse of it I mean":If an angle is more than $90$ the intersection is outside.So We have to prove the reverse of the lemma and what you have said but I can't discover why the intersection is inside and the reverse could you please give a proof?

Comment: Recall that the point of intersection of the perpendicular bisectors is also the circumcenter of the triangle, the center of the circle which contains all three vertices. A side contains the circumcenter if and only the angle opposite is a right angle.

Comment: @Joffan Why?Could you please explain more?

Comment: To go into more detail of John Wayland Bales answer.  The intersection is on all 3 bisector and the bisector is all point equidistance for the endpoints.  So the three vertices to intersection are equal and thus the radii of a circcle.  If a circle is cut into semicircle by a diameter: angle formed by a point in the left semi circle and the endpoints of the diameter is 90.  angle formed by point one endpoint of diameter and a point on right semicicle is accute..  By point and endpoint of diamter and point on left semicirle is an obtuse angle.  So this is if and only if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comparative/comprehensive situation helps as the biggest angle $C$ lies opposite the largest side $c$, we consider inequalities comparison with right triangle at center of a set of three.

[image: TriasCircCenter]

Draw three triangles $ CAB $ in a circle with a common vertex at $C$ making obtuse, right and acute angles and three variable sides $c = AB.$

Perpendicular bisectors of sides in each case meet at circle center/circumcenter $O$ which in these three cases *lie outside the triangle, on the hypotenuse and inside the triangle* respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors of the longest side and either of the shorter sides. Note that joining the midpoint of these two sides makes a smaller triangle similar to the full triangle.

Now for an obtuse triangle, the perpendicular bisector of the shorter side will start inside this midpoint triangle and hence will cross the longest side before its midpoint, putting the intersection of those two bisectors outside the triangle.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The intersection of the perpendicular bisectors of a triangle is the circumcenter.  If the triangle has all angles acute, the circumcenter is within the triangle, and conversely.  If the triangle is right, the circumcenter is on the hypotenuse (since the hypotenuse is the circumcenter's diameter), and conversely.  Therefore, if the triangle is obtuse, the point lies outside the triangle, and conversely.

Answer (score 0):

(*The following is not a formal proof, though it could be developed into one with some work.*)

Thought experiment (building upon @JohnWaylandBales' comment): imagine a triangle $\triangle ABC$ with $B,C$ fixed and $A$ a freely moving point. Let $O$ be the circumcenter, then $O$ can lie on the line $BC$ iff $OB=OC$ by definition of the circumcenter i.e. $O$ must be midpoint of segment $BC\,$. In that case $\widehat{A} = 90^\circ$ since it subtends diameter $BC\,$. It is intuitively obvious that $O$ depends *continuously* on $A$, so the angle $\widehat A$ only ever changes from $\lt 90^\circ$ to $\gt 90^\circ$ when $O$ crosses the line $BC$. It follows that $O$ is on the same side of $BC$ with $A$ iff $\widehat A \lt 90^\circ$. Finally, $O$ is *inside* triangle $\triangle ABC$ iff it is on the same side with any vertex relative to the opposite side which, from the above, is equivalent to all angles being acute. Conversely, it is *outside* iff at least one angle is obtuse.